# MySql Vs. Postgresql for a blog application

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I am designing a blog application. Which of these fits better?
In which use cases will mysql be good and for what use cases will postgresql be good?

Comment: Both will be fine for such an application. Although I can't think of anything that MySQL does better than Postgres. But I can think of a lot of things that Postgres does much better than MySQL

Comment: SQLite will be good enough.

Comment: Can someone tell me some stuff which postgres is really good at but mysql isn't?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - You can't think of "anything"?  MySQL does many things better than postgresql, particularly around flexible replication topologies, operational usability, and easier upgrades.  What postgres is better at is nearly everything in the SQL-land.  This is all unlikely to be relevant for a blog application, however.

Comment: http://www.wikivs.com/wiki/MySQL_vs_PostgreSQL

Comment: You need share about use before good recommendations can be made. Is this a personal blog application for just you, or will it have lots of users and traffic? Will the features be complex or simple? Does it need to run popular shared web hosting plans? And why not just use Wordpress or another blog engine as a starting point?

Comment: Depending on requirements maybe a better question is do you even need use an ACID compliant database?

Comment: @MarkStosberg : I just want to know if I use postgres as a database for  blog app which caters to both personal blog with low and high traffic, then where can I fall in a pitfall?

Comment: @StarShip3000 : Can you tell me the use case where I might need ACID compliant and where I might not need acid compliant?

Comment: @AramBhusal Is it important that your data is treated with ACID rules (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID)? Basically if speed is all that matters ACID is not needed.  I personally haven't worked on anything where non-ACID is desired.  It's a an edge case typically to go non-ACID.

Comment: @StarShip3000 even I was thinking the same !! Havent encountered any use case to not use ACID. IS postgres not ACID compliant?

Comment: It's fully ACID compliant. From a infrastruture point of view go with PostgreSQL, it will provide a solid foundation that you can build on.  Plus it gives you the chance to learn a very worthy database for future needs.  For the most part you are asking what is better brand x or brand y shoe. Both will let you walk and run, though I would pick PostgreSQL brand myself.

Comment: If it is just a blog, go MySQL.  The MYISAM tables may be helpful.  On the other hand, PostgreSQL is better if you are doing heavier-duty work or if you want your data model to be accessible across multiple apps (as in an ERP or the like).  See my answer below for more on this as well.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL's home territory is in CMS.  It will be good enough.  I like PostgreSQL as much as the next guy but a blog will work on either, and MyISAM tables might actually be really nice there.

As for where PostgreSQL does better than MySQL, here is my take. There are two big areas:

1. Advanced data modelling and
2. Multi-application databases

The first means that PostgreSQL is far more mature at doing complex data modelling than MySQL is.  It has a very mature extensible type system, a wide range of procedural languages, and a great deal of flexibility in how these languages can be plugged into existing queries.

If that wasn't enough, the fact is that you can essentially build your data model in PostgreSQL based not only on what information you are storing but what information is commonly derived from what you are storing.  This makes things like not-first-normal-form actually sane to use where they are needed.  Add collections and multiple inheritance in table structure and you have a very sophisticated data modelling platform.  For examples, see my recent [blog entries](http://ledgersmbdev.blogspot.com).

On to the other side.  MySQL developers tend to see the application as the bottom tier of the application stack, while PostgreSQL developers tend to see the application as the center of the data environment.  Besides the content management system market, MySQL's other major market is in applications where data is not expected to be exposed to more than one writing application at a time.  This leads to a significant difference in handling data validation, etc.

In PostgreSQL validation is always equally strict.  If the app expects special error treatment it had better call functions or casts to handle this explicitly.  For example, if I want to store up to a maximum of 144 characters in a text field, I can:  `insert into mytable values (?::varchar(144));` and absent such, PostgreSQL will throw an error if it isn't crystal clear what the application wants, and whether it will fit into the data schema as defined.

MySQL however places the application in charge of defining the data validation rules.  The sql_mode setting (which includes such things as whether '0000-00-00' is a valid date or whether '2008-02-30' can be stored in a date field) is something any application can set without restriction, and the DBA has no way of restricting this.  So while PostgreSQL allows the relational and object-relational interface to serve as a public API, it is essentially intended largely to be a private API for applications in MySQL.  This is a **huge** difference and not readily understood by many people trying to make the choice.  This leads to major differences in application design.

MySQL is a data storage and reporting solution for *your application.*  PostgreSQL is a data centralization, modelling, and reporting solution for *your organization.*  The two are remarkably different.

Comment: The best comparison for a laydba I've ever read.

Answer (score -1):

Are you writing the blog application just for fun for yourself, or are you planning to make it available for everyone to download (think WordPress) or sell it as a product?

If it's going to be something that anyone can download and install, then it's a no-brainer:
It **must** work with MySQL if you want it to succeed...because practically every web hosting provider out there offers MySQL databases, but not PostgreSQL (at least **I** never saw a provider with PostgreSQL).

**No matter if MySQL or PostgreSQL is better from a pure technical point of view - if you want people to use your app, it must work with what's available at their web hosters.**

Comment: Overwhelming majority of shared hosting providers that offer cPanel also offer Postgresql. So this availability issue is almost non-existance.